# IE7 z-index doesnt work event after adding position?

Tags: html, css

IE7 z-index doesn't work even if I add position: `absolute` or `relative`

Is there any other solution ? I add other divs lower z-indexes but doesn't work

```css
.gallery {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    display: block;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -44px;
    top: 70px;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: 3000;
    display: none;
}
.sub_menu {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    float: left;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 40px 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 930px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, IE handles `z-index` differently from other browsers. This might be helpful: http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: IE7 is less than 1% marketshare so don't worry about it and if someone has requirements that talk about IE7 just tell them it's not a real problem.

Comment: We need to see more of your HTML and CSS as a parent node might be preventing the stacking from working properly.  Can you please provide a URL or a trimmed-down fiddle.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: I can't test right now, but if i remember right you need to have both `left` or `right` and `top` or `bottom` so that ie 7 will apply the `z-index`. For `.sub_menu` you only have `top` so you either need to add `left` or `right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `z-index` and IE it is sometimes required to use `!important`

```css
.gallery {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    display: block;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -44px;
    top: 70px;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: 3000 !important;
    display: none;
}
.sub_menu {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    float: left;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 40px 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 930px;
    z-index: 1000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
!important
```

Should be used as a last result.

**Try the following before hand**

```
body{
    z-index: -1
} 

.gallery {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    display: block;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -44px;
    top: 70px;
    width: 980px;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
 }

.sub_menu {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    float: left;
    height: 21px;
    padding: 40px 35px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 930px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```